# jquery delete element In sharepoint content editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sharepoint

I have created a jquery to create a tab for list item and that jquery will insert  element tag to style the tabs on the paeg load,but problem is that when ever the page loaded again and again the  element tag also recreated .so, that  element tag created  many times as we visited it is created .So, i need to delete the  element tag before it is created again.

```
<script src="/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/TabsForSharePointFormscolor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var tabConstructor = {
    tabs:[ {name:'Activity',fields:['Name'], mouseOver:'This is the first tab',tabStyle:''}],
    settings:{
        viewAllFields:{show:true,name:'All fields',mouseOver:'This tab shows all fields',tabStyle:'',clickFunction:''},  
        orphanFields:{show:true,name:'...',mouseOver:'All orphan fields',tabStyle:''},  
        breakTabRowAt:null,  
        hoverTabColor:'#FFF68F',  
        selectedTabColor:'#B9D3EE'
    }
};  

init_buildTabbedForm(tabConstructor,1);  



  </script>
```

In this init_buildTabbedForm will create  element.

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQuery Empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty/). So something like

```
$(".tabId").empty()
```

Comment: I need to delete <style> </style> element completly before creating it again ,will it work,thanks for the answer.

Comment: It's hard to give more exact advice without some code samples. Can you update your original question with some of your code?

Comment: So you want to remove the 'hoverTabColor' and 'selectedTabColor' styles?

Comment: NO i need to remove the whole  <style> </style> elements tag to be removed

Comment: $("#tabid").removeAttr("style");